# (SELECT JOIN?) Como pegar uma quantidade de registros de uma coluna especifica, de outra tabela (quando há chave estrangeira)

Tags: mysql

Minha tela de listagem mostra os dados da tabela "PESSOA".

Existe uma tabela chamada MATRICULA q tem a coluna `idpessoa` fazendo referência.
Nessa matrícula existe um campo chamado EVADIDO pra saber se a pessoa se evadiu daquele curso que se matriculou.

Como eu faço pra saber, na minha LISTAGEM, quantas vezes essa pessoa (aluno) já se evadiu de uma matricula (curso), sendo que não tem esse campo na tabela de pessoa, somente pela tabela de matrículas.

Acho que ficou fácil de entender, meu sistema usa esse select atualmente:

```
SELECT pe.* FROM pessoas pe
INNER JOIN cidades ci ON (ci.idcidade=pe.idcidade) 
INNER JOIN estados es ON (ci.idestado=es.idestado) 
WHERE pe.removido = 'N';
```

Esse Inner JOIN Cidades e Estado é essencial também pois na minha listagem aparece o nome da cidade por referência por um ID (as cidades e estados são cadastrados no banco)... o mesmo pra estado.. Preciso deixar tudo isso dentro do mesmo select.

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `pessoas`
--

CREATE TABLE `pessoas` (
  `idpessoa` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idcidade` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ativo` enum('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `removido` enum('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `login_ativo` enum('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `data_cad` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `estado_civil` enum('S','C','D','V') DEFAULT NULL,
  `etnia` enum('B','P','N','O','A') NOT NULL,
  `data_nasc` date NOT NULL,
  `naturalidade` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rg` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rg_orgao_emissor` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rg_data_emissao` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nis` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `filiacao_mae` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filiacao_pai` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` int(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `complemento` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sit_ocupacional` enum('EM','DE','AU','AP') DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_profissao` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_empresa` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcd_visual` enum('BAI','CEG') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcd_mental` enum('MEN') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcd_auditiva` enum('SBP','SBT') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcd_fisica` enum('AMP','1MS','1MI','CAD','NAN','AMS','AMI','OST','PAC','PAR') DEFAULT NULL,
  `vinc_empregaticio` enum('CA','AU','ME','FP','OU','NT') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcd` enum('S','N') NOT NULL,
  `pcd_qual` enum('F','A','M','V') DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcd_grau` enum('L','M','A') DEFAULT NULL,
  `nacionalidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `escolaridade` enum('FI','FC','MI','MC','SI','SC') NOT NULL,
  `formacao` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sit_escolaridade` enum('C','I','T') DEFAULT NULL,
  `sit_escolaridade_curso` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sit_escolaridade_periodo` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') DEFAULT NULL,
  `instituicao` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `curso_fundat` enum('S','N') DEFAULT NULL,
  `curso_fundat_qual` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_membros_familia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `renda_familiar` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `observacoes` text,
  `prog_federal` enum('S','N') DEFAULT NULL,
  `prog_federal_qual` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `encaminhado_instituicao` enum('S','N') NOT NULL,
  `encaminhado_instituicao_qual` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone1` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone2` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ultimo_view` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ultima_senha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `avatar_nome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar_servidor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar_tipo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar_tamanho` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexo` enum('M','F','N') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


--
-- Estrutura da tabela `matriculas`
--

CREATE TABLE `matriculas` (
  `idmatricula` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idhorariooferta` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idpessoa` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `removido` enum('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `data_cad` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `matricula` int(8) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao` enum('M','I') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
  `evadido` enum('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `desistente` enum('S','N') DEFAULT 'N',
  `reprovado` enum('S','N') DEFAULT 'N'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: @JulianoGuimaraes posta a estrutura das tabelas, para podermos usar como referencia.

Comment: Ta editado, pode conferir ^^ valeu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um subselect com select count, por exemplo:

```
SELECT pe.*, (SELECT count(0) 
              FROM matriculas ma
              WHERE ma.idpessoa = pe.idpessoa 
                  AND ma.evadido = 'S') quantidade_evasao 
FROM pessoas pe
INNER JOIN cidades ci ON (ci.idcidade=pe.idcidade) 
INNER JOIN estados es ON (ci.idestado=es.idestado) 
WHERE pe.removido = 'N';
```

Porem neste caso mostra quantidade de evação independente do curso, mas seria só adicionar mais clausulas no subselect de acordo com o que você precisa.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu preciso! É pra mostrar de todo os cursos mesmo! <3